# Braintree Authorization Exception, why?

Tags: exception, braintree

I am trying to generate a client_token like so:

```
private static BraintreeGateway gateway = new BraintreeGateway (
            Environment.SANDBOX,
            "merchant_id",
            "public_key",
            "private_key"
    );

@ApiMethod(name = "genClientToken", path = "client_token", httpMethod = ApiMethod.HttpMethod.GET)
public ClientToken genClientToken() {
    return new ClientToken(gateway.clientToken().generate());
}
```

Whenever I do this I get a Braintree Authorization Exception, even though the merchant_id, public_key and private_key are all supplied as put in the Sandbox dashboard.

Why am I getting this `com.braintreegateway.exceptions.AuthenticationException` and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Calling `gateway.clientToken().generate()` is the correct way to generate a `clientToken` and it seems like there is a separate issue [with your credentials.](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/general/exceptions/java#authentication-error) Please reach out to support at support@braintreepayments.com with more details.

Answer (score 0):

from the doc at https://developer.paypal.com/braintree/docs/reference/general/exceptions/dotnet#authentication-error

> Authentication Error Braintree.Exceptions.AuthenticationException
>
> Raised when your API keys are incorrect. If you're getting this
> exception when first integrating, double-check that you haven't
> accidentally tried to use your sandbox keys in production or
> vice-versa.

it says there's a problem with your API keys.

However I encountered this same error when switching from sandbox to production API keys and it was to do with the roles assigned to the user who created the API keys which are being used. So while the API keys were correct, the exception returned because the user had insufficient privileges. Would be better if Braintree returned a different exception in that case but it doesn't.

you need to add the following roles to the user in the Braintree control panel:

Transactions:

- Create Sales
- Submit Sales for Settlement

you may also need the read-only roles as well.

here's the full list of roles and the rights granted
https://developer.paypal.com/braintree/articles/control-panel/users-roles/role-permissions

Comment: You are looking at an Authentication exception. OP is asking about an Authorization exception

Comment: Read the last line in the OP it's an authentication exception

Answer (score 0):

Just adding one additional comment to this thread, in addition to roles/permisions -- if you have multiple merchant accounts with Braintree and you don't get the merchant account name correct it can also cause an authorization error -- I had a typo in my merchant account name in my code that caused this.